# German equivalent of the Japanese expression 黄色い声援, “let out a yellow cheer”

Tags: phrase-request, japanese

In Japanese, we use the expression 黄色い声援, "*(let out) a **yellow** cheer*" to describe a collective ecstatic exclamation that extremely enthusiastic female fans utter at the sight of a famous actor or the performance of their favourite band.

This expression is confined to denoting ***females*** who, fangirling over their idol, burst out cheering and screaming wildly. Your guess is as good as mine, though, as to why we use the colour *yellow*.

An audience letting out a yellow cheer, 黄色い声援: [羽生結弦　アスリートの魂 (YouTube)](https://youtu.be/jrFxZVViA_I?t=463).

Comment: I think what you are looking for is *"kreischen"*, at least thats what girls do at concerts and stuff.

Comment: *Kreischen* ist indeed right, but in German, it's the same sound your car brakes make when you stomp the pedal at full speed.

Comment: "Kreischen" can also mean a small circle. (Yes, irrelevant, but as we started collecting things that could also be designated by the term...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Various expressions are possible. None of them is as florid as your Japanese one. (But then, who would dare to compete with Japanese when it comes to floridness).

"Kreischen" (mentioned first above by RoyPJ) is probably the most common word used for that phenomenon, although the word is void of poesy; it is rather matter-of-fact-ish.

I list a number of possible sentences that come to my mind:

> Als der Star auf die Bühne sprang, fingen die Mädchen an zu kreischen.
>
> Als der Star die Gitarre ergriff, wurden die weiblichen Teenager hysterisch.
>
> Als der Star zu singen began, fielen die Backfische in Ekstase.
>
> Die Mädchen gerieten in Verzückung.
>
> Die Mädchen schrien wie am Spieß.

The only one here, so far, with a certain graphic quality is "schreien wie am Spieß", although this is not a particulary good match as initially it means screaming of deadly pain and terror, not of joy. Anyhow, the sound would be similar. Perhaps one could enrich it by combining:

> Die Teenie-Mädchen gerieten in Verzückung und schrien wie am Spieß.

---

**Experiment zone**

<sub>Speaking of acoustics, I see one more way to express this (based on the experience of time spent on my uncle's farm when I was a teenager myself): *Als sich der Star das Hemd vom Leibe riß, erhob sich aus den Kehlen der Groupies ein Geschrei wie zur Futterzeit im Schweinestall.* But note that this is nothing I have ever heard being said, nor does it seem appropriate for use in any normal context. I made it up ad hoc based on the acoustic similarity. Town-dwellers would not understand the analogy, I suppose, but villagers will.</sub>

Comment: Backfisch? Echt? Boha, [retro](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Backfisch%2CTeenager&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CBackfisch%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CTeenager%3B%2Cc0) ;-)

Comment: @Stephie  Ja, stimmt; mir war das Wort halt vor ein paar Tagen wieder in die Quere gekommen, als wir  nach einem deutschen Äquivalent für das bulgarische лохманка suchten. Gibt es was Aktuelleres?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Wie wäre _die Teenies_?

Comment: @Marizpanherz  Ja, *Teenies*... eindeutig geläufiger als das sperrige "*die weiblichen Teenager*". Aber würde *Teenies* nicht auch männliche einschließen?

Comment: Time of your life on that farm, eh? ;)

Comment: Backfisch ist in der Tat etwas aus der Mode (genau genommen war der schon veraltet, als ich noch ein Teenager war), aber im Interesse der Vollständigkeit finde ich es gut, dass auch der hier erwähnt wurde. Heutzutage begegnen mir Backfische ja sonst nur bei der Nordsee (bei, wohlgemerkt, nicht in!)

Answer (score 4):

I propose "Die hauptsächlich weiblichen Fans waren völlig aus dem Häuschen." Source Rhein-Zeitung, September 3rd, 1997: "Backstreet's Back, und die Teenies **sind aus dem Häuschen**."